# How to listen the change of a particular view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to listen to the change in the dimensions of a particular view. The change can happen because of orientation change, re-sizing of some other views etc.

I have tried this by using `MYVIEW.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(MYGLOBALLAYOUTLISTENER)` but this is called every time the global layout is changed irrespective of any change in the MYVIEW.

How can I just listen to the change in the dimension of MYVIEW only.

I can use OnGlobalLayoutListener and then check for the coordinates of MYVIEW and then launch the desired methods accordingly but this doesn't appear to be a concrete solution.

Please share with me if there is any other way.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you could [try the onLayoutChangeListener on your view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLayoutChangeListener.html), which will give you the new layout bounds of your view every time the app needs to redo it's layout

Comment: Thanks for your reply trippedout ! 
I think the onLayoutChangeListener doesn't get updated on orientation change. It is called before the layout is redrawn after the orientation change. I want something that works in the same way as the  onWindowFocusChange works but for a specified view.

Comment: have you tried overriding the onLayout call of your actual view? if the onLayoutChangeListener wont get fired, i bet you onLayout is called when orientation changes

Comment: The onLayoutChangeListener does fire after orientation change but the problem is it is fired before the layout is laid on the screen. I am searching for a method that will fire once the layout is completed on the screen. This is achievable using onWindowFocusChange or using viewTreeObserver but as I mentioned above I cannot use them.